# What NoSQL database to use?

Tags: database, many-to-many, nosql

I am developing an app that has many-to-many relationship between its entities and also need to store files (pdfs, emails, images, etc). I will be using Java code. I would like to know which NoSQL database to use. I was thinking of using Neo4J for the many-to-many relationship with gridfs to store the files. Has anyone done something like this before? Need to store the complex relationship between entities and also files (which can be huge.. 16MB-1ooMB).

Comment: Actually there is no NoSQL DB that provides many-to-many relationship model. But if you want to use a NoSQL DB you can perform many query to reach your data.

Comment: You could do this with a normal RDBMS by simply storing the files as blobs in the database or storing a link to them on some file system or storage server. Why do you think you need a nosql database for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that i help you, but i try to use mongo for model many-to-many.

And my experience is terrible... 

because, official mongo documentation says: for model many-to-many use DBRef.

And when i use DBRef i need dereference my documents references.

And i don't found any working example how to do it....

I wrote own - but it provides many bugs...

Perhaps i'm looser, and don't understand how works with it, but i think when you will be look to mondo think about it.